# Need help with event handling syntax in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to add an event in my VB.NET code. I have done VB.net programming but not well experienced in event handling.

I have declared like this

```
public WithEvents FormEventCapture As vFormAgent.__vFormAgentLib_Event
```

Then i put the following code in form load event

```
FormEventCapture = new vFormAgent.__vFormAgentLib_FormEventEventHandler()

AddHandler FormEventCapture.FormEvent, AddressOf Me.FormEventCapture_FormEvent
```

Is it correct?

When i compile i get the following error

```
Delegate 'vFormAgent.__vFormAgentLib_FormEventEventHandler' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor. (BC32008)
```

So i need to pass an argument to this constructor then i changed as follows

```
FormEventCapture = new vFormAgent.__vFormAgentLib_FormEventEventHandler(AddressOf Me.FormEventCapture_FormEvent)
```

Then i get the following error

```
Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'vFormAgent.__vFormAgentLib_Event' because 'vFormAgent.__vFormAgentLib_Event' is not a delegate type. (BC36625)
```

I am not able to figure out what is the problem.

Can any one tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out what is the problem.

FormEventCapture_FormEvent should have same signature as delegate function i.e. __vFormAgentLib_FormEventEventHandler.

When i changed the signature of the FormEventCapture_FormEvent , it did not give the error.

But i am getting some run time error, If i do not succeed in figuring out i have ask you all for help.

Thanks.